# only header is showing up in posts

Tags: headers

Header section is showing up. 
Home page and other pages are fine. But for post. This error is coming 
It was working since morning.

https://repairmymobile.in/flash/spreadtrum-upgrade-tool/

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you install the theme via FTP or did you install using the zip upload?

I'd guess that you missed some files when uploading.

Comment: No file was removed or added.

Comment: Try `define( 'WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '256M' );`

Comment: It was working in morning

Comment: added no result

Comment: Fatal error in your template using after header.php. Define `WP_DEBUG, true`. If you using ssh, execute wordpress index.php by CLI. `php index.php`. It will show you errors

Comment: I am not a expert. Plz send tutorial link

Comment: https://codex.wordpress.org/WP_DEBUG

Comment: It worked by increase memory limit to 256

Comment: Told you @Sidh bro.